# Sliding page transitions with new content pre-loaded underneath

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, transition, preload

I am working on a project where the client wants a way of transitioning between content that basically works like page turning on an e-reader app. When you click on a link to go forward, the current content slides to the left and new content is **revealed** as it slides. If you click on a link to go backwards, the content slides in from the left and is superimposed. (If you're jumping to a page further off it's fine for the page to reload.)

There needs to be a distinct URL for each content block, and ideally this should work all the way down to IE7. Assume there are at least 50 pages, each with at least 2-300 words.

I know there are lots of jQuery page transition options, but most of the ones that I've looked at slide in the new content while the old content is sliding off or fades in the new content after the old content is gone (think slide.js). What I need is basically curtain.js that is vertical, triggered by a link instead of scrolling, and doesn't need to load in all of the content on the page at once.

Here's one way I've come up with possibly building this:

- Current content is loaded in from the database (or whatever)
- Content for the previous and next pages are also loaded in and stored in hidden divs
- When a link is clicked, the current page slides off (or the previous page slides in)
- The content that's no longer needed is deleted
- New content is "preloaded" with AJAX and hidden
- Local URL also changes with AJAX

[Here's a crude diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwnDi.jpg)

That seems really inelegant, though. Is what I've outlined above possible to do? What would be a better way of doing this?

I am okay with JS/jQuery and PHP, learning AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest jQuery UI tabs

1. No need to deal with AJAX. Just get the server to spit out the 50 pages of texts once and that's a wrap.
2. It's pretty straightforward to hook into the API, which gives you more control over the entire procedure. Enough control to hook up a function that updates the address bar when you tab through.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but how would tabs help with the page-forward/page-backward animation mechanics? Also it seems like it wouldn't scale to load in 50 pages of text at once but it would make this a lot simpler.

Comment: I assumed you'd be using CSS to control the transition and get that precise animation of the page change. http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ can apply/remove classes and your css transitions do the work.

Comment: You can keep two tabs visible and stacked that way in CSS, then have a class that overrides the positioning on the top of the stack and moves it offscreen. Use css transition to make it an animation. Callback function can do the setup (loading a new page and populating it with content, for example) and all that needs to be done is switch classes :)